# Can you create an interactive menu using a string split?

Tags: java, string, split, menu

For a project at school, my professor wants us to create a menu using a string split. She did not cover how to do this, so I am a little lost.

Here are the assignment instructions:

"For project 4, I want you to take project 3 and use the command line based menu on it. This means instead of an interactive menu, you'll use the command string version i.e.

Buy 1
History
quit

Your program must show that you can handle implementing two types of interface to your program. One using an interactive menu that asks them what they would like to do, and one using a command string menu where you enter the command as a string and your program uses string split."

I can't seem to find any other resource that shows how to make a menu based on string user input. I have no idea where to start, I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
System.out.println("Welcome! Enter a command. \n"
                    + "Enter 1) Buy Bitcoin \n"
                    + "Enter 2) Sell Bitcoin  \n"
                    + "Enter 3) Print Balance \n"
                    + "Enter 4) Print History \n"
                    + "ENTER 5) print USD\n"
                    + "Enter 6) Exit Program\n");
            choice = myscanner.nextInt();
```

Comment: I think it is about using the console for input.

Comment: Without having more details on what you did before, not sure to understand properly the requirements of the next phase but I would expect that you have to have to prompt the user to input some command, read that input as a String and then split it and parse it to meaningful commands.

Comment: I added the menu that I made for my project 3. Basically, the whole program tracked the live value of bitcoin, and was a fake stock buy and sell game. you started with $20,000 and you can buy and sell and it would calculate it. I did that fine, but I'm really confused about how to make this menu using string split. Hope this brings some context.

Comment: so, with that context, I do confirm my previous tip. Replace your scanner call to read a full String line instead of an int. And parse the full line to understand the content of it (that's where split will come handy :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated in the comments by Wisthler you are supposed to read the whole line and split the String. Following code example show you an approach how to solve this task:

```
    // Example command
    String command = "print balance";

    String[] commandSplitted = command.split(" ");

    // You have to add a length check for the array
    if (commandSplitted[0].equals("print")) {
        // command part 1 is print
        if (commandSplitted[1].equals("history")) {
            // command part 2 is history
            // command is print history
            // ...
            System.out.println("enter 4");
        } else if (commandSplitted[1].equals("balance")) {
            // command part 2 is balance
            // command is print balance
            // ...
            System.out.println("enter 3");
        }//... depending on the amount of commands you might want to use a switch case on the split parts
    } // else if ...
```

Your next step would be to complete this code and add your reader (You will have to modify it) from the previous task.

Please be aware that this is only an approach and not fully functional.